# Database : Different primary keys linked to single foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of

```
users 
[attributes : user_id] 
websites
 [web_id, user_id[foreign key] ]
```

I want to store userids corresponding to each website a user_id visits . Mysql dont provide dynamic storages, so I am not able to store website in a single database . Problem is how to link primary keys to single foreign key.

So I have links/domain names of websites , and userids of all user who visit these websites ,single user can visit multiple website  now I want to store this information in tables such that I have webid/website name which points to userids , but since there are multiple userids associated with a single webpage/website , how to create table to store this information?

Comment: You should probably clarify your question, may be give a better example of what you're trying to accomplish. I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry , did some edit !! its more like 2NF problem it seems , correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Are you talking about a many-to-many relation between a `users` table and a `websites` table? This is usually being implemented as an additional `(user_id, website_id, unique(user_id, website_id))` table holding that relation.

Comment: @lanzz Why unique and not pk?

Comment: @Aitor primary key is semantically equivalent to `NOT NULL UNIQUE`, but it also implies that you want to be able to point foreign keys at it, which seldom (but definitely not never) makes sense for m2m intermediary tables. I guess it's a matter of preference or convention, but I'd rather go with explicit `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` constraints

Comment: @lanzz makes sense. I have never seen it before. Thanks!